# Dependent dropdown: keeping users selection after post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm looking for an easy way to keep the user's selected choice (dropdown) after submitting the form. I'm working with dependent (dynamic) dropdowns to narrow the user's choice. The second dropdown doesn't show the selected option. This is because of the dynamically generated javascript function I think. How do I get this to work?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
    {
        switch (listindex)
        {
        case "manual" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("open","open");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("deliverd","delivered");
            break;
        case "online" :
            document.getElementById("status").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
            document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("open","open");
            document.getElementById("status").options[2]=new Option("delivered","delivered");
            document.getElementById("status").options[3]=new Option("shipped","shipped");
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <title>Dynamic Drop Down List</title>
    <body>
    <form action="testdep.php" method="post">
    <div class="category_div" id="category_div">Source:
        <select id="source" name="source" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option id="" value="">Select source</option>
        <option id="manual" value="manual">MANUAL</option>
        <option id="online" value="online">ONLINE</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">Status:
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<select name="status" id="status"><option value="">Select status</option></select>')
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <select id="status" name="status">
            <option id="open" value="open">OPEN</option>
            <option id="delivered" value="delivered">DELIVERED</option>
        </select>
        </noscript>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["source"])){$source=$_POST["source"]; echo $source;echo "<script>document.getElementById('".$source."').selected=true;</script>";}
if(isset($_POST["status"])){$status=$_POST["status"]; echo $status;echo "<script>document.getElementById('".$status."').selected=true;</script>";}
?>
```

Comment: can u do a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)  of  the dropdowns

Comment: you could peek at `localStorage` to keep track of selected item maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the final solution myself. Thanks again Louys to help me out!

Please feel free to post if you have a better solution.

```
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <form action="testdep2.php" method="post">
          <select id="source">
            <option disabled selected>PLAYS</option>
            <option>PLAY 1</option>
            <option>PLAY 2</option>
            <option>PLAY 3</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>
          <select id="status">
            <option disabled selected>DATES</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Appends options to the second select, based on the first.
        $("#source").on("change",function(event){
          var x= document.getElementById("source").selectedIndex;
          switch(x)
          {
          case 1:
            $('#status') .empty();
            dynamicOption = $("<option disabled selected>").text("Choose date");
            $("#status").append(dynamicOption);
            dynamicOption = $("<option>").text("DATE 1.1");
            $("#status").append(dynamicOption);
            dynamicOption = $("<option>").text("DATE 1.2");
            $("#status").append(dynamicOption);
          break;
          case 2:
            $('#status') .empty();
            dynamicOption = $("<option disabled selected>").text("Choose date");
            $("#status").append(dynamicOption);
            dynamicOption = $("<option>").text("DATE 2.1");
            $("#status").append(dynamicOption);
            dynamicOption = $("<option>").text("DATE 2.2");
            $("#status").append(dynamicOption);
          break;
          case 3:
            $('#status') .empty();
            dynamicOption = $("<option disabled selected>").text("Choose date");
            $("#status").append(dynamicOption);
            dynamicOption = $("<option>").text("DATE 3.1");
            $("#status").append(dynamicOption);
            dynamicOption = $("<option>").text("DATE 3.2");
            $("#status").append(dynamicOption);
          break;
          }
        });

        // On submit, store info in local storage.
        document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].addEventListener("submit",function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("Submited");
          localStorage.setItem("source",document.getElementById("source").selectedIndex);
          localStorage.setItem("status",document.getElementById("status").selectedIndex);
        });

        // If there is local storage on load (or return from submit), use the info.
        if(localStorage.getItem("source")!="undefined"){
          // Set the first select to what is in "memory".
          document.getElementById("source").options[parseInt(localStorage.getItem("source"))].selected=true;
          // Triggers the script that creates the dynamic options.
          $("#source").trigger("change");
          // Now that options are present in the second select, set it to what is in "memory".
          document.getElementById("status").options[parseInt(localStorage.getItem("status"))].selected=true;
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in plain JS, using localStorage.
Add this after the `form`.

And remove the PHP code you posted about it.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

// On submit, store info in local storage.
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].addEventListener("submit",function(){
  localStorage.setItem("source",document.getElementById("source").selectedIndex);
  localStorage.setItem("status",document.getElementById("status").selectedIndex);
});

// If there is local storage on load (or return from submit), use the info.
if(localStorage.getItem("source")!="undefined"){
  document.getElementById("source").options[parseInt(localStorage.getItem("source"))].selected=true;
  document.getElementById("status").options[parseInt(localStorage.getItem("status"))].selected=true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I've added this JS after the </form>. Cannot keep de selection for both dropdowns now.

Comment: Sorry for that... My bad. It has to be `getElementsByTagName` instead of `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Hey Louys, I have the same result. First dropdown keeps the selection but the second one doesn't.

Comment: I have made a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vmMwVM?editors=1011) with this code and it is working. So, do you have a live link to this page? I could look at it.

Comment: No I have not. Your code is working fine, but the form is not dynamic anymore. I need the first dropdown to show titles of theater plays and the second one showing the available dates of the selected play. After submit, I need to keep the selected options to remain visible in the dropdown menus.

Comment: Ha. so if the options of the second dropdown are created after a selection of the first one... That is the issue. The script is suggested is correct... But you'll have to also create that `option` element. My script tries to set an option as selected... But if it isn't there... Sure it fails. I will edit the codepen with something to try.

Comment: Is it ok to use jQuery?

Comment: Here is a second [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qmGEmN?editors=1011) where the second `select` depends on the first.